# Two dataframe with incomeplete values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two dataframes A and B with id: 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5... they have same columns: id, quantity and attr_1. But they have some missing values like this:

```
A

  id  quantity  attr_1  
0  1        NaN      0       
1  2        23       1       
2  3        19       NaN      
3  4        20       1    

B

  id  quantity  attr_1  
0  1        11       NaN       
1  3        Nan      1       
2  4        20       1      
3  5        19       0
```

I do not want to merge them together because I need to process them separately.
How do I fill these missing values from each other and generate a result like this:

```
expected for A:

  id  quantity  attr_1  
0  1        11       0       
1  2        23       1       
2  3        19       1      
3  4        19       0   

expected for B:

  id  quantity  attr_1  
0  1        11       0       
1  3        19       1       
2  4        19       1      
3  5        19       0
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html

Comment: what is the logic here? expecte for A and expected for B is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work quite easy:

```
dfA.fillna(dfB)
dfB.fillna(dfA)
```

This work when indexes are the same. Otherwise you have to set it before execute the code above:

```
dfA = dfA.set_index('id')
dfB = dfB.set_index('id')
```